# Polling portlet issue in IBM Websphere Portal

Tags: multithreading, crash, websphere, polling, portal

I have a problem diagosing an production issue at work. Basically we have an Intranet Portal site running on IBM Websphere Portal (Version 5 or 6). So pages are pretty much built on composition of different portlets, i.e. News portlet, generic links portlets, graphic image portlets etc. We also have a Polling portlet created for internal users to vote on specific questions. However, there's being an issue with this polling portlet causing an outage of the entire Portal when (I was told) multiple users voting at the same time (or configuring the portlet at the same time) that builds up the number of running threads. I've being trying to duplicate the problem on QA/Test environment with load testing tools (e.g. Fiddler) but failed to reproduce the issue. There's limited amount of information I've being given when they approach me for finding the root cause of the problem in the code. Without being able to duplicate the issue there's no way I'm able to ensure I have fixed the problem.

Could anyone advice what other ways I can go in reproducing the issue? Has anyone ever come across with similar issue before? How did you go about reproducing it?

I'm sorry I can't provide much information apart from describing the problem to you. Cheers

Comment: See my answer below for a possible explanation. Note, however, that an outage is best troubleshot by issuing traces, etc. My answer might not  describe the reason for your outage, but it's definitely a possibility given the information you provided.

Comment: Thanks Issac, much appreciated for your prompt reply to my questions. First of all, the issue happened twice last year, I was investigating the issue but no luck. Only thing that we certain is that the outage was indeed caused by the polling portlet. Due to the nature of the portlet, it might be reasonable to expect high volume of requests. In which case how do we implement the code in the portlet to handle this in WAS servers? The portlet is already using Synchronised() method.

Comment: see my reply in a comment below my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that what you were told about the Portal outage has to do with Portal Server running out of Web Threads.

WebSphere Portal is merely an application built on top of WebSphere Application Server. WebSphere Application Server provides the JavaEE runtime itself. To make a long story short, WebSphere Application Server maintains *thread pools* for certain tasks.

One of the thread pools is the "Web Container" thread pool. If the value is set to `X`, then at most `X` Web requests can be processed at the same time; the `X+1`th request will have to wait.

An outage can occur if the thread pool is max'd out and there's a backlog of requests waiting for a thread to be available.

You should check the size of the Web Container thread pool and take it from there.

Comment: @dale: I'm not sure what you mean by saying that the portlet is already using the `synchronized` method. Synchronizing over what, exactly? If the outage is indeed characterized by the Web Container thread pool being stressed, there's nothing you can do within your code to battle it. The problem is not (I suppose) with your code doing `synchronized` or not; it is with WebSphere itself running out of Web Container threads so it can't process too many HTTP requests at once.

Comment: Thank you Isaac for clarifying. In regards to reproducing the problem, I'm not sure if the way I did it was correct while using stress testing software. Do you reckon a stress testing software would be good enough to reproduce issues like this to justify with evidence that a root cause is found? What free licencing software would you recommend instead of the one I already use?

Comment: @dale: yes, a stress testing tool would be good. Try max'ing out WebSphere's Web Container thread pool by issuing a load of requests and see what happens. About free tools... sorry, I never used any free tool but Apache JMeter should do the trick.